# pytorch tensor conversion - tensor of tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two tensors in one dataset as below
[image]

how i can convert into tensor of tensors? to get final output as below:
[image]

I tried to convert as below:

```
for i in (transformed_dataset):
sample = i['image'], i['label'].view(1)
```

im getting tuple

```
for i in transformed_dataset:
sample = torch.cat((i['image'], i['label'].view(1)), dim=1)
```

also cat dosent work as due different number of dims ( 2 and 1 as above) and I cannot convert first torch to be 1 dim as its 224x224 =50176

Answer (score 0):

resolved by:

```
samplelist = []
for i in transformed_dataset:
    sample = i['image'], i['label'].view(1)
    samplelist.append(sample)
```